# How to model constraints for Order and OrderPosition tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key, unique-constraint

There is the following scenario:

**Table Orders**
PK - OrderID

**Table OrderPosition**
PK - OrderID
PK - OrderPosition

OrderID is the primary key of table orders.
OrderID and OrderPosition is a composed primary key of table OrderPosition.

If a entry is OrderPosition is added the OrderID used must exist in the table Orders and the combination of OrderID and OrderPosition in the table OrderPosition must be unique.

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and tried to add a foreign key constraint but this doesn't work as the number of columns differs. So what's the correct way to model this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table Orders**

PK - OrderID IDENTITY(1,1)

**Table OrderPosition**

PK - OrderPos_ID IDENTITY(1,1)
OrderID
OrderPosition

+`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (OrderID, OrderPosition)` if needed

+`FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT (OrderID) REFERENCES Orders(OrderID)`

## upd

```
CREATE TABLE #o (o_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE #op (o_id INT, pos_no INT, PRIMARY KEY(o_id, pos_no))

ALTER TABLE #op ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (o_id) REFERENCES #o(o_id)
GO
SELECT * FROM #o o INNER JOIN #op op ON op.o_id = o.o_id
GO
```

Comment: Do I really have to add a new colum just to model this constraint? Is there no other way?

Comment: Normalize you data model and you will not have such problems. Also google for "multiple columns in clustered index key".

Comment: Could you please help me to understand why and which normal form this model violates? It looks like 3NF with a composed primary key to me. In my understanding a primary key does not have to be an identity column. How should the model be designed to prevent this issue?

Comment: _"In my understanding a primary key does not have to be an identity column."_ - of course it does not. You may have all of your columns in PK or don't have PK declared at all. But you have to be aware of all the consequences of such design decisions.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ivan! But why is this model not normalized? Unfortunatly I can't change the design as it's used in the ERP but I try to understand the problem and how I should model the reporting database.

Comment: Reporting database? Why do you need FKs at all?

Comment: Because there are transformations (in other places) and I want to ensure data integrity. I just don't know how to model this following best practice. The usage of Order and OrderPosition seems to be common to me, but I'm still not sure how to model this. Independent of the question if I need a FK in this situation, I might need it in another. :)

Comment: Well, if you want to keep this structure then you should be able to create FK. It's likely you attempted to create reversed FK - from Orders to OrderPos. If it is so then - yes - it should fail. Switch parent<>child tables in FK definition to the required order: OrderPos references Orders.

Comment: I thought this was the issue and tried it both ways, but it didn't work in the SSMS GUI. This Script does excactly what I need. Thank you very much! :)